# Public Joomla items producing a 403 access denied

Tags: joomla2.5

I've recently upgraded from Joomla v1.5.26 to v2.5. This installed v2.5 in /jupgrade.

I had to reinstall K2 in /jupgrade, and the new K2 picked up my old K2 items, as the database had been copied.

However, all of the K2 items had a blank Access level. This meant when I selected the item from the front end navigation menu, I was requested to login. After I logged in, I received a 403.

I then set the access level to Public for all of the K2 items, and ensured the menu entries were pointing to the correct K2 items.

However, the 403 error remains on the front end.

Why is a page forbidden when its access level is Pubic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that jUpgrade does not set permissions on articles OR categories.

Once I set permissions on categories, articles displayed OK.